# SQL - Selecting in three steps

Tags: sql

I am a completely newbie in SQL. I would really apreciate your help in solving this problem or simply pointing the proper terms to search by in google.

I have a database like this:

```
A  B
1  2
1  7
2  3
2  4
3  5
5  8
8  9
10 11
```

The user is assumed to inform a specific id for A. I need to build a query that returns columns A and B following a logic that I can only think in three steps. First, return all records where A is equal to id informed by user. In this step, collect all B column values. After that,in the second step, use the B column values collected in first step to return all records where column A is equal to these B values already mentioned. Again, in this step, collect all B values related to the records returned in the second step. In the third step, the same thing, return all records where A column is equal to the B values collected in the second step.

I know that I was not clear enough. Just to give some examples.

If user chooses id = 1, SQL returns:

```
A  B
1  2
1  7
2  3
2  4
3  5
```

If user chooses id=2, SQL returns:

```
A  B
2  3
2  4
3  5
5  8
```

If user chooses id=3, SQL returns:

```
A  B
3  5
5  8
8  9
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This looks like something that should be handled by a recursive SQL query. The syntax for recursive queries differs for each DBMS but is supported by most. I suggest you look into specific examples of recursive queries in the DBMS you're using.

Comment: If you only need 3 steps, recursion isn't required because you can write those 3 steps on your own using `UNION` (remove duplicates) or `UNION ALL` (keep duplicates) between 3 select queries, like in the answer by @Rahul_Jain below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks messy, but will work.

```
SELECT A,B FROM table 
WHERE A in (1)

UNION

SELECT A,B FROM table
WHERE A in 
(SELECT B FROM table 
WHERE A in (1))

UNION

SELECT A,B FROM table
WHERE A in 
(
SELECT B FROM table
WHERE A in 
(SELECT B FROM table 
WHERE A in (1))
)
```

Replace 1 with user selected id at all 3 places

Comment: NOTE: This only works for the three step problem. If you need the query to work for any number of steps, that will require a recursive query.

Comment: Can u say what is wrong with this approach:` select A, B
from table
 join (select B from table where A = (1)) as t1 on t1.B = table.B
 join (select B from table where A in t1.B) as t2 on t2.B = t1.B
where (A = (1)) or (A in t1.B) or (A in t2.B)`

Answer (score 1):

i think you searching some one like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM test_sql t1
where t1.a = 3

union

SELECT *
FROM test_sql t2
where t2.a in (
  SELECT t1.b
  FROM test_sql t1
  where t1.a = 3
)

union

SELECT *
FROM test_sql t2
where t2.a in (
  SELECT b
  FROM test_sql t2
  where t2.a in (
    SELECT t1.b
    FROM test_sql t1
    where t1.a = 3
  )
)
```

**#### i think your 2nd output is wrong**

Comment: do u know what is wrong with the aproach in the next answer? thank u